# How to select all in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to query all in case the information of the following variable is not pass to the function.

```
$user = User::where('isVerified', $a)
        ->where('country', $b)
        ->where('province', $c)
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
```

How can i make this query available for the data getting in case without information of country, province pass to the query? Which mean any data is verified. at the same time, i need to get the filtered data in case they do provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query dynamically and use `isset()` to check if the variable values are set or not.

```
$user = User::where('isVerified', $a);

if(isset($b)){
   $user -> where('country', $b);
}

if(isset($c)){
   $user -> where('country', $c);
}

$user -> orderBy('created_at', 'desc') -> paginate(6);
```

Comment: Hi. May i know why it returning method not found? :( Please help. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338792/call-to-undefined-eloquent-method-appends-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::where('isVerified', $a);

if ($b)
{
    $user->where('country', $b)
}

if ($c)
{
    $user->where('country', $c)
}

$user->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
```

You might need to use isset($b) if you don't set them to null if nothing is set.

Comment: Hi, i'm testing to use the method and it returning some error, please help. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338792/call-to-undefined-eloquent-method-appends-in-laravel